S-record row manipulation
We need each row from srec file consist of 2x16-bit adrress and 16x16-bit (or 8x16-bit) data.
Hi,
We are working with microcontroller that can store 16-bit data on one address. For storing data into the microcontroller flash memory we use .srec format that is generated using CCS. Part of the srec file is below:

In the picture you can see that 16-bit data is stored at each address.
Each row consist of 2x16-bit address and 15x16-bit data.
Microcontroller use Flash API for storing data in flash. To use specific functions from this API, I need to create row that consist of 2x16-bit address (address should not be divided by two or something similar) and 16x16-bit data (also could be 8x16-bit data). This one 16-bit data must be from next row and checksum must be also recalculated with this new data. Address in next line must be adapted.
Can this be done using the s-record tool?
Thank and kind regards.
